# What's the best way to see what messages are in $.validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am wondering what the best way of finding out what messages are in the validator would be?

I have tried alerting $.validator.messages but that just returns [Object object]. Does anyone know how to alert each message?

I haven't found an answer while searching the net. So hoping someone will be able to help.

Comment: this way $.validator.messages[] ?

Comment: You should have enough reputation to realize that tag-spamming is frowned upon here.  The jQuery Validate plugin is not the same as the [tag:jquery-validation-engine] plugin.  Also, this question seems like an attempt to get around the rules against posting [duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905594/jquery-custom-validation-and-mvc-validationmessagefor-help-required).

Comment: @Sparky Sorry I didn't realise that the validation engine was a different one. This question was a different question entirely to the other one. It was related in that I needed it to try and Debug the other one, but its not the same question.

Comment: You may think it's a totally different question, but it appears to fully depend on the link to your other question.  In every case, questions need to be self-contained and not rely on other SO questions or external links.

Comment: @Sparky Ok fair enough, it wasn't meant to depend on the other link, it was meant to be a standalone question. I linked to the other one for a bit of background. My apologies. Would you like me to delete one of them? I have just answered my own question on the other one, so maybe i should just delete it.

Comment: I'll leave deleting the other question up to your best judgment.  The criteria should be, _"will this help future readers?"_.  As far as this question, I think you should remove the link and add the bare minimum amount of information required to make a concise and complete question, again using the same criteria about helping others.

Comment: @Sparky No worries. Doing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is alerting because it is an object, whose default to string implementation prints `[Object object]`.

The best tool in such case is to use console logging, from your browsers developer tools like

```
console.log($.validator.messages)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RNx7R/3/) - to view the logged message, check the browsers console window

Comment: Brilliant that works. Sadly I cannot see my messages in their. Not sure if that is where they are meant to go.
If you look at the jquery on my other question, where I am adding the rules. Are the messages supposed to then go into the validator messages? Or am I looking in completely the wrong place?

Comment: Brilliant that is exactly what i was after, thanks for you help! If i could vote more than once i'd give you 10 upvotes :)